# How to get a column which contains a particular data in a row excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is probably very easy for experienced user of excel, but I couldn't find a way to do this, so I asking this question.

I have particular range of cells, let's say E5:M5, only one cell of this range will contain 1, other will contain  0. I want to reference, first cell of that column (which contains label). I want to do this by using a formula in another cell. In the end, that another cell should have label name as its value.

I wanted to post image elaborating what I want, but it seems I can't do that.

Anyway, can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Have a look at [`Range.find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: In the future you really need to provide more details about what sort of data you have, and what result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want to use a formula rather than VBA as it is not recommended for inexperienced Excel users to use VBA. Use this formula to determine the first column out of your set, which has "1" as a value:

```
=match(1,E5:M5,0)
```

If by 'label name' you mean you have a header or something (let's assume in row 4), you can use the index function to pull the value from the mirror set of rows above the match function, like so:

```
=index(E4:M4,match(1,E5:M5,0))
```